# Data layer for existing JS project

Tags: javascript

We have a big project with big amount of front-end code + **jQuery**.
I would like to have a library to implement into existing project which would let me handle data in a friendly way.

**Most annoying thing which happens now is this:**

```
 1. grab some data from DOM element. Modify it a bit, filter it.
 2. send AJAX with that data.
 3. receive AJAX.
 4. filter AJAX. Modify it a bit.
 5. update DOM with new received modified data.
```

This can be really automated and I believe there are ways to do so however from my experiments `backbone.js, angular.js, ember.js and similar libraries` do not work very well in my case as it is too hard to imlement them into existing project. When starting from scratch - they are awesome in my opinion.

I have read about implementing only new parts in them but this seems not to be the case as 
I would like to improve existing code.

**What I would like -** some lightweight module on top of jQuery maybe which would handle these things for me in a more friendly fashion.

**Why downvotes?**

I am not starting a flamewar, asking for open question or so. I am asking for a tool for a problem. Downvoter - at least give your insight what's wrong with the question.

Comment: have you tried extjs?

Comment: Why not write a jQuery plugin?

Comment: @Satya I have tried it a few years ago. Isn't it a fully fledged framework ?

Comment: @Andy - I am all for writing some code on my own! But I believe there must be better alternatives. Proven alternatives.. :)

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Well I've described what I have tried and search for an alternative